# Multiple select in html file upload

Tags: html, file-upload

I am creating a basic appliaction where I am allowing the user to upload images but I want that user should upload a maximum of 2 images.
So any idea that how I should do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiple attribute on the input tag of type file `<input id="files" type="file" multiple>` 
That only solves the half the problem, as multiple would allow any number of files.
You can solve that by using following ways:

- Provide a user with information that only 2 files are allowed.
- Some times user might select more than 2 files even after the information, in that case use javascript to report the error

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="files">Upload Images
    <span>Maximum of only 2 files allowed
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="file" id="files" multiple>
  <div id="error" class="error">
    Maximum of 2 files only can be uploaded
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper label {
  color: blue;
}
label > span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.error {
   color: red;
   font-size: 20px;
   display: none;
 }
</style>

<script>
 files.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if(e.target.files.length > 2) {
    error.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    error.style.display = "none"
  }
})
</script>
```

Here is link to the codepen https://codepen.io/shivakumarjakkani/pen/vYmXVxy

Answer (score 0):

you can user multiple element ex:

```
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br><br>
```